# connect php with mssql while using iis

Tags: php, sql-server, connection

I have successfully configured php in IIS. sample php pages working fine. now i want to connect it to sql server i tried it by downloading a mssql .dll file in ext folder,I also tried by installing a extension for windows driver, then also it is not working. please help to sort out this issue. I am Using php5.3.19 for the same.

Comment: check `phpinfo()` or `php -i` to see if the extension is loaded. Please expand on *Not working* - that doesnt help anyone

Comment: In PHP 5.3, you need to use the MS-provided (*not* bundled) "sqlserv" driver, not the "mssql" driver.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use PHP 5.3 with SQL Server (2005 and above), you will need the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).  There are two versions available:  2.0 and 3.0.  3.0 includes support for SQL Server 2012 and PHP 5.4.

You can find instructions for installing the dlls and interfacing with SQL Server in a [TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx).

To install the extensions, you must move them into your ext folder and add a line to php.ini to load them, like the following:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll
```

Once this is done, restart the web server and load phpinfo in order to see if the extension has loaded.  If it has loaded correctly, you should see [a "sqlsrv" section in PHPInfo](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-imagefileviewer/CommunityServer-Wikis-Components-Files-00-00-00-00-05/1307.Figure2_2800_sqlsrv_2900_.jpg_2D00_550x0.jpg).

When the time comes for you to begin writing PHP that connects to SQL Server, make sure you have installed the native client.  The current version is the [SQL Server 2012 Native Client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx).  References for the API are available [on TechNet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296152%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php).

Finally, consider upgrading to PHP 5.4.  The 3.0 versions of the drivers support 5.4 but the 2.0 versions do not;  if you cannot install 3.0 on your system, you can find a 5.4-compatible version of the DLL (sqlsrv-5.4-nts-snap.zip or
sqlsrv-5.4-ts-snap.zip) [on PHP.net](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/).  I have had good results with these versions.